# How do I handle a WebSocket close from the client in Yaws?

Tags: erlang, websocket, yaws

I have implemented a simple *appmod* that handle WebSockets and echo back the messages. But how do I handle an `ws.close();` from the JavaScript client? I have tried with the code below, but `handle_message({close, Reason})` is never called and `ws.onclose = function(evt) {}` is never executed on the JavaScript client.

When I use the same JavaScript client code interacting with a node.js websocket, the client receives an `onclose` event immediately after `ws.close();`.

Here is the code for my simple *appmod*:

```
-module(mywebsocket).
-export([handle_message/1]).

handle_message({text, Message}) ->
    {reply, {text, <<Message/binary>>}};

handle_message({close, Reason}) ->
    io:format("User closed websocket.~n", []),
    {close, normal}.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer:

As of github commit 16834c, which will eventually be part of Yaws 1.93, Yaws passes a new callback to your WebSockets callback module when the client sends a `close` message. The callback is:

```
{close, Status, Reason}
```

where `Status` is either the close status sent by the client, or the numerical value 1000 (specified by RFC 6455 for a normal close) if the client didn't include a status value. `Reason` is a binary holding any optional reason string passed from the client; it will be an empty binary if the client sent no reason.

Your callback handler for a `close` message MUST return `{close, CloseReason}` where `CloseReason` is either the atom `normal` for a normal close (which results in the status code 1000 being returned to the client) or another legal numerical status code allowed by RFC 6455. Note that `CloseReason` is unrelated to any `Reason` value passed by the client. Technically `CloseReason` can also be any other Erlang term, in which case Yaws returns status 1000 and passes the term to `erlang:exit/1` to exit the Erlang process handling the web socket, but based on RFC 6455 we suggest simply returning the atom `normal` for `CloseReason` in all cases.

Original answer, obsoleted by Yaws github commit 16834c:

Yaws never passes a `{close, Reason}` message to your callback module. Rather, `{close, Reason}` is a valid return value from `handle_message/1` should your callback module decide it wants to close the ws socket.

I modified the `websockets_example.yaws` file shipped with Yaws (version 1.92) to call `this._ws.close()` in the client if the user enters the "bye" message on the web page, and added an alert to the `_onclose` function to show that the `onclose` event is triggered. In this case the alert occurred, I believe because the "bye" message causes the server to close the ws socket explicitly. But I then modified the example to call `this._ws.close()` in the client no matter what message the user enters, and in that case no alert for `onclose` occurred. In this case, a check with `lsof` showed the ws connection from the browser to Yaws was still present.

So, for now I believe you've hit a bug where the Yaws websockets support isn't detecting the client close and closing its end. I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: Thanks, this was informative. I use the client code I posted on [How to handle WebSocket messages in an appmod using Yaws?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187809/how-to-handle-websocket-messages-in-an-appmod-using-yaws) where I have a button "disconnect".

Comment: Using Chrome 17.0.963.46 I don't see any `close` message going from the browser to Yaws when `ws.close()` is called. I also tried a version 16 of Chrome and didn't see one with it either. What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Chrome 16. The same client code worked with a node.js server.

Comment: Please disregard my previous comment, the lack of the `close` message was just operator error on my part.

Comment: I've verified it's a bug in Yaws. Fixing.

Comment: Interestingly in Chrome 17.0.963.46 (and maybe other versions too) if you send call `ws.send()` followed by `ws.close()`, the `close` message goes across the wire before the sent message.

Comment: Thankfully I was wrong about Chrome too, there is no message ordering problem. I missed the original message from browser to Yaws in tcpdump because Chrome sent it as a masked message, which is perfectly allowable by RFC 6455, but which made it such that I didn't see the text I was expecting to see in tcpdump.

Comment: I can't find any websocket example in Yaws 1.95. And I can't load the module with `handle_message({close, Status, Reason})`. That is not documented on http://yaws.hyber.org/websockets.yaws either. Is this still an issue? I can't get this working with Yaws 1.95.

Comment: There are several websocket examples in Yaws. [Here's one](http://yaws.hyber.org/websockets_example.yaws) you can run right from yaws.hyber.org, for example, and [here's the source code](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/blob/master/www/websockets_example.yaws) for that example.

Comment: Also, see the [Yaws PDF documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/yaws.pdf) for more information about websocket support in Yaws. And yes, it all works perfectly fine in Yaws 1.95.