# Failed to load setuid_drv: "Driver compiled with incorrect version of erl_driver.h" when running Yaws

Tags: macos, erlang, yaws

I installed the latest release of Erlang and the lastet Yaws from the master branch. But when I try to run yaws I get an error of `Driver compiled with incorrect version of erl_driver.h". How can I fix this? Doesn't Yaws run on the latest Erlang release? I run this on Mac OS X 10.6.

```
jonas$ yaws
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> 
=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Jun-2012::00:43:08 ===
Failed to load setuid_drv (from "/usr/local/lib/yaws/priv/lib") : "Driver compiled with incorrect version of erl_driver.h"
=ERROR REPORT==== 18-Jun-2012::00:43:08 ===
FATAL {'EXIT',normal}

=INFO REPORT==== 18-Jun-2012::00:43:08 ===
    application: yaws
    exited: {shutdown,{yaws_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
    type: permanent
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,yaws,{shutdown,{yaws_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,yaws,{shutdown,{yaws_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm successfully running the latest version of Yaws from github master on OS X 10.7.4 under Erlang R15B01 — it definitely works:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin bcc 11.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 11.4.0: Mon Apr  9 19:32:15 PDT 2012; root:xnu-1699.26.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ yaws -i
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
1> 
=INFO REPORT==== 18-Jun-2012::10:01:33 ===
Yaws: Using config file /usr/local/etc/yaws/yaws.conf
```

Is there any chance you compiled your Yaws sources in the past with a previous version of Erlang (R14Bxx or older), and then tried to build again under R15B01 without first doing a "make clean"? The Erlang driver interface changed between versions 14 and 15, which might explain this error.

Comment: I tried to download and compile it again, now it works. I don't know what went wrong last time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This answer is no longer meant to be an answer. It's here only to prove its own invalidity.

---

The latest version of <s>(release version of)</s> Yaws should run happily with the latest Erlang distribution on OSX. <s>Please try downloading the source code of Yaws from http://yaws.hyber.org/download/ rather than from the master branch from GitHub. The master branch of Yaws might be a little bit experimental.</s>

Comment: The latest release of Yaws (1.92) is very old, and the master branch contains some bugfixes I need. E.g [How do I handle a WebSocket close from the client in Yaws?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9233292/213269)

Comment: I'm a committer on the Yaws project, and I can say with certainty that the master branch of Yaws is stable and is never intended to be experimental.

Comment: @SteveVinoski Thanks for your correction. Your comment renders my answer useless. I was about to delete it for the cleanness of SO, but I realized other people may also have the incorrect assumptions as I did, and I decided to keep my useless answer anyway. Thanks again.